# How to fix laravel relationship query where clause?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to get data from the 'files' table through the 'computer_files' pivot table but the query puts an 'is null' into the query and therefore it doesn't return with the data. However, if I change the is null to an ID and run it as an SQL command it does give the data back.

I have tried going through the laravel docs but it didn't help. What I don't want to do is to use raw queries.

This is the files relationship function:

```
public function files(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\File', 'computer_files', 'computer_id', 'file_id');
}
```

This is what I do to get the data and currently gives back an empty collection:

```
$computer = Computer::where('computer_id', session('computer_id'))->first();
pr($computer->files);
die;
```

Also the 'toSql()' gives this:

```
select * from `files` inner join `computer_files` on `files`.`id` = `computer_files`.`file_id` where `computer_files`.`computer_id` is null
```

I expect to see an ID in the query instead of 'is null' so then it will give back the results that I need.

Comment: I would guess your `session('computer_id')` is `null`.

Comment: already checked on that and it is not because that is being set when you login and if i set it to a number it is still the same. also if it would be null then the '$computer' would be null and therefore the files variable would fail.

Comment: `computer_id` is the primary key in the `computers` table, right? Have you set `protected $primaryKey = 'computer_id';` in the `Computer` model?

Comment: yes that is the primary key and i did not set it. but as soon as I did the query changed to ```where `computer_files`.`computer_id` = ?```. Thanks